# MD5 Decryption Python no ouput and errors

Tags: python, md5

I am trying to decode MD5 hashes via brute force.

So far I have the following code:

```
import hashlib
import random
import string
import timeit


# function for random 5 letter word-number string
def random_string():
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    for i in range(5):
        result = "".join(random.choice(letters))
    return result

def decrypt(hash):
    process = True
    while process:
        word = random_string()
        encode_word = word.encode("utf-8")
        digest = hashlib.md5(encode_word).hexdigest
        # hash = hashlib.md5(word.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        if digest == hash:
            process = False
                
    print(word)

hash = "a74edf83748e3c4fa5f31ec10bad79db"
decrypt(hash)

execution_time = timeit.timeit(decrypt, number=1)

print(execution_time)
```

However, no output is produced and no errors are produced and I cannot seem to see the issue here. Am I missing something?

Comment: MD5 is one way hash function.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski But I am trying to decrypt via brute force, in which I generate many random 5 letter words, encrypting them and seeing if their digest matches the original hash given

Comment: I don't think `random_string()` is correct.  You are generating a single-character string I think....

Comment: Also, you have to actually call the `.hexdigest()` method (you have it right in a comment, but not the code).